# Array to string conversion in php while updating values

Tags: php

I want to change password in database on the base of User Name and want to              get message 1 if query is execute after comparing values with array other wise     pring message 0.
But this code gives me

> Array to string conversion error

Any idea how how to compare user name with database base available users and then after executing query to get message if user name is not matched with database present user

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("wst",$con);

$un = $_REQUEST['user'];
$pass=$_REQUEST['pass'];

$flag['code']=0;


$query = mysql_query("select * from driver");
while($user=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    if(in_array($un, $user)) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE driver SET password= '$pass' WHERE       userNamme='$user'",$con);
        $flag['code']=1;
    }
}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1):

$user is array.

```
userNamme='$user'
```

try

```
"UPDATE driver SET password= '$pass' WHERE userNamme='" . $user["userNamme"] . "'"
```

and change fetch method from mysql_fetch_array to mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: The MySQL extension is deprecated. You should look into the MySQLi functions. They are included in php, you do not need to install anything.

Answer (score 0):

You Can make use of mysql_num_rows().
Here is the Updated Code.

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("wst",$con);
$un = $_REQUEST['user'];
$pass=$_REQUEST['pass'];
$flag['code']=0;
$query = mysql_query("select * from driver where userNamme='$un'");
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($result>0)
{
mysql_query("UPDATE doctor_details SET password= '$pass' WHERE            userNamme='$un'");
$flag['code']=1;
}
print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Thanks bro nice solution